# MongoDB identity in ASP.NET throws "Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name" when UserManager tries to acccess db

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-identity

Last week my code was working. Then yesterday a started getting "Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name" whenever I tried to access the Users collection in my MongoDB database
Im using AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDbCore to store users.

My MongoDbContext has the faulty function, where partitionKey is null, whenever userManager tries to access it.

```
public IMongoCollection<TDocument> GetCollection<TDocument>(string partitionKey = null)
{
    return Database.GetCollection<TDocument>(partitionKey);
}
```

My ApplcationUser model is set up like this:

```
[CollectionName("Users")]
public class ApplicationUser : MongoIdentityUser<Guid>{}
```

The builder has the identity service set up like this:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
    .AddMongoDbStores<ApplicationUser,ApplicationRole,Guid>(mongoDbContext)
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

And the program fails whenever I try to access the "Users" Create/Login
`ApplicationUser appUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);`
Where _userManager is
private UserManager _userManager;

PS.
RoleManager also fails to access the db
When I hardcoded accessing the Users like:

```
public IMongoCollection<TDocument> GetCollection<TDocument>(string partitionKey = null)
{
    return Database.GetCollection<TDocument>("Users");
}
```

I could sign in and create users

I've tried reinstalling the NuGet packages, updating to the latest .NET 7 version , downgrading to .NET 6 to no avail